# How to run scheduled task for laravel 6 on plesk windows server

Tags: laravel, windows, scheduled-tasks, plesk

I tried below step to run scheduled task on plesk windows server, but no luck

1. Selected Run as command
2. In Command text box added `C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP7.4\php.exe`
3. In with argument text box `C:\inetpub\vhosts\mydomain\httpdocs\artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

[image]

Am getting below error
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by selecting "Run a PHP script" instead of "Run a command" task type and added artisan path in Script path field and `schedule:run` in argument field.
[image]